# Combo chart that can be extended with custom series?

Tags: .net, winforms, charts

After some serious posts reading I couldn't really see the answer to my question, so I decided to ask, hoping I can get a useful answer.

I need to create a .NET chart that supports mixing of standard bar, line, point series and that can be extended with custom series.

Any suggestions?

So basically the chart I need to create is similar to the image attached  (link below), but I need these extra yellow lines to be drawn somehow to mark the beginning and the end of certain events on the time scale.
 I haven't yet chosen a library because I don't seem to find one that's going to do the job. We're in "selective" mode yet to make sure we will only do the job once.

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/e91d4720434e%2F.NET%20chart%20control.png

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you need and where you got struck. Share some screen shot of what you need, what you have and your current code. Also which chart library are you using? Is that [MSChart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or?